# C# - How to get a long type variable defined by user in a TextBox and use it in a mathematical operation

Tags: c#, casting, long-integer

I need a Text field of my program to be treated as a LONG type variable and be processed in a mathematical operation. The value of this variable needs to be specified every time by the user and I want the program to treat this value not as an integer but as a long indeed.

I have treated other fields as integer and they work fine with this kind of code:

```
HourField.IntValue
```

now notice that .IntValue that obviously says to the program to take the content of the HourField whatever is in it and treat it as an integer.
But unfortunately there is no equivalent for the long type in fact if I try to write .LongValue, C# just doesn't recognise this function....there are other similar functions like .FloatValue or .DoubleValue etc. but there is no such thing as .LongValue.
However I even tried to use this kind of syntax:

```
Convert.ToInt64(FileSizeBytesField);
```

or something like that and in theory the compiler doesn't give me any error for the compilation etc. but if I try to actually make the calculation by pressing the button the program crashes and Visual Studio tells me that the type of casting is invalid.
Please please pease help me with this. It's the last thing I need to actually finish my program!!!

P.s. I am posting some screenshots of what I got and of my source code. Thanks

[program's source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKHoC.png)

[Debugging error in Visual Studio after program crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF6tv.png)

Comment: is FileSizeBytesField a string?  if not (if it's a control etc.) then get the string value and pass this to ToInt64.

Comment: Hi well actually no because otherwise the compiler gives me errors basically saying that I can't use a string to be in a mathematical expression and I think I need casting, you know I'm just starting out with C# and I am not too sure still how it works but I have a rough idea. but I have tried to assign FileSizeBytesField as a string and as far as I can remember it didn't work. I didn't declare it as a variable I just want to take the content of the box and treat that one as a long type data.

Comment: What are the data types of `HourField` and `FileSizeBytesField`?

Comment: @Dour High Arch Hour Field I have it as an integer and FileSizeField I want it to be treated as a long variable defined by the user through a Text Box so the program will have to read that value and implement it with the mathematical expression.

Comment: @VittorioBasile Just add your code as **text** not as screenshot. That makes the code searchable and allow others with a similar question to easily find this one. I guess only due to screenshots your question has negative rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `FileSizeBytesField` you are trying to take a value from is an instance of `NSTextField` or another subclass of `NSControl`. [In that case](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoMac.AppKit.NSControl/), you can take the value of control using properties like `IntValue` or `StringValue`. So, to convert the value to `long` type try this:

```
Convert.ToInt64(FileSizeBytesField.StringValue)
```

Or, using more common approach already suggested by [Hooman Bahreini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46146528/2595805):

```
long fileSizeBytes;
if (long.TryParse(FileSizeBytesField.StringValue, out fileSizeBytes))
{
  // use fileSizeBytes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Parse, to convert the string value to long

```
long l = long.Parse("453216");
```

If you want to ensure that your input is a valid number, you can use tryParse

```
if (long.TryParse("45263572", out l) == true)
{
  // use long value
}
else 
{ 
  // input is not a valid long value... handle the situation here
}
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for your comment. Well yes this seems to at least solve the crashes but the problem I get is that apparently when I set that numerical value to the long type it uses that value ALL THE TIMES regardless of what the user inputs in the Text Box and I don't want that I want to take a variable number each time and use it with a mathematical expression that's all but it needs to be long obviously thanks

Comment: What's the type of FileSizeFiled? You need to get the string value of FileSizeFiled and convert it to long. For example, if FileSizeFiled is a textbox, then you would use:  long.Parse(FileSizeField.Text) in your mathematical expression.

Comment: Hi, yes it is a Text Box although I guess that's the way you would do on Visual Studio on Windows but in this case I'm using the version for Mac and for some reason it doesn't accept TextBox.Text format...:/ by the way I'll try and do long.Parse(FileSizeField) and see if it works. P.s. FileSizeField is of course the name that I gave to the Text Box where the user will have to give the input.